# How can I simplify this code for reordering a list of objects using an "order" property that each object has?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to create an algorithm that will go through a list of objects and sort them, but not exactly sorting like moving the items of the list based on a property, **the order of the original list does not change**, what defines the order is not how the objects are sorted inside the list but a property that every object has called `order` which is an integer number.

To make it a bit more complicated this reordering is done based on another list, here called the `reorderer_list`, which contains dictionaries that represent the objects, with all their properties including the `order` but they are just simply sorted in the correct order inside this `reorderer_list` (their `order` properties may also be incorrect)

Basically an example of the situation would be:

```
reorderer_list = [{"order": 7, "name": "Tom"}, {"order": 5, "name": "Sara"}, {"order": 6, "name": "John"}]
```

And the original list, which is in an unknown order of these three people, should in the end become

```
[{"order": 5, "name": "Tom"}, {"order": 6, "name": "Sara"}, {"order": 7, "name": "John"}]
```

or

```
[{"order": 6, "name": "Sara"}, {"order": 7, "name": "John"}, {"order": 5, "name": "Tom"}]
```

doesn't matter, both are correct (They are both correct because the sorting of the items inside the final list does not matter, what matter is **only** the `order` property, I just used this example to explain that. The original list will contain these three names (for example) sorted in whiever order inside the list with whichever value for `order`, it doesn't matter, in the end the original list `order` property should be arranged to match the reorderer_list actual sorting of the items inside of it.

Also is important to notice sometimes the original list and reordered list may not be of same size, the objects that had their position changed always will exist in both lists

Here is what I have already tried:
`list_data` is the original list and `reorderer_list` is the new list with the correct order

```
# This will find the differences between the reordered list and the original list
changedOrderItems = []
changedOrderItemsOrders = []
for index, product in enumerate(list_data):
    #Sizes may be different, avoid IndexError
    if index == len(reorderer_list):
        break
    # Is different
    if product.name != reorderer_list[index]["name"]:
        #Append to temporary list, the items from reorderer list
        changedOrderItems.append(reorderer_list[index])
        #Append to temporary list, the order property of these items
        changedOrderItemsOrders.append(reorderer_list[index]["order"])

#Sort the orders list
changedOrderItemsOrders.sort()

# Cycles through the temporary list and finds the index of the respective object in the original list and sets it's order number according to the sorted changedOrderItemsOrders list
for i, item in enumerate(changedOrderItems):
    from_data_index = next((index for (index, d) in enumerate(list_data) if d.name == item["name"]), None)

    list_data[from_data_index].order = changedOrderItemsOrders[i]
```

It works but I want to know if there are any ways to improve this mess?

Comment: `sorted(reorderer_list, key=lambda x: x["order"])`?

Comment: @pault He doesn't want to sort `reorderer_list`, he wants to use that to get the ordering for another list.

Comment: There needs to be a clearer example of the true inputs and the desired output.

Comment: I don't understand this question. Why are both orderings correct?

Comment: It would be easier if you replaced `reorderer_list` with a dictionary that maps the names to their desired order. `{d['name']: d['order'] for d in reorderer_list}`

Comment: It might be helpful to show what the original list is before the sort. It's not clear (to me) what you're starting with and what you're trying to change.

Comment: Both orderings are correct because what defines the order is the `order` property, not how they are actually sorted in the list, **but** with the reorderer_list what truly matters is actually the sorting of the list. I'm sorry if this is confusing because it's actually confusing to me as well, I am struggling to explain this in a simples way

Comment: @NathanDanzmann If the code you have does what you want and you want to investigate on ways to improve it (simplicity, performances, etc.), it is much easier (for you and for others) to wrap it up in a function with **clear** inputs and outputs, as well as providing a couple (ideally more than one or to) test inputs paired with the expected outputs. As of now one of the inputs (`list_data`) is completely unknown to the reader.

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```py
def change_order_value(items):
    new_orders = [item['order'] for item in sorted(items, key=lambda x: x['order'])]
    for new_order, item in zip(new_orders, items):
        item['order'] = new_order
    return items


reorderer_list = [{"order": 7, "name": "Tom"}, {"order": 5, "name": "Sara"}, {"order": 6, "name": "John"}]
print(change_order_value(reorderer_list))
# [{'order': 5, 'name': 'Tom'}, {'order': 6, 'name': 'Sara'}, {'order': 7, 'name': 'John'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

IIUC this is what the OP wants:

```
initial_list = [{"order": 5, "name": "Sara"}, {"order": 6, "name": "John"}, {"order": 7, "name": "Tom"}]

reorderer_list = [{"order": 7, "name": "Tom"}, {"order": 5, "name": "Sara"}, {"order": 6, "name": "John"}]

def answer(initial_list, reorderer_list):
     sorted_order = sorted([e["order"] for e in reorderer_list])
     d = { e["name"]: order
           for e, order in zip(reorderer_list, sorted_order) }
     for e in initial_list: 
         e["order"] = d[e["name"]]
```